# .day Component returns "incorrect" day in Swift

Tags: swift, foundation

My date object returns "incorrect" day from some reason, I have no idea why.
This output is taken from the debugger:

```
(lldb) po date
▿ Optional<Date>
  ▿ some : 2022-05-13 21:06:55 +0000
    - timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : 674168815.716091

(lldb) po date.get(.day)
14
```

The get function:

```
extension Date {
func get(_ components: Calendar.Component..., calendar: Calendar = Calendar.current) -> DateComponents {
    return calendar.dateComponents(Set(components), from: self)
}

func get(_ component: Calendar.Component, calendar: Calendar = Calendar.current) -> Int {
    return calendar.component(component, from: self)
 }
}
```

Any ideas what am I missing?

Comment: please show get function code.

Comment: What time zone are you in?

Comment: Oops, added code

Comment: So it was the 13th when you executed the code? Note that the date is printed using GMT but the day is for your time zone

Comment: No it was the 14th. But sounds like that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier:"GMT")